# WinGet Install - My app receives "Installer hash does not match"

Tags: windows-store-apps, winget, microsoft-store

My application gives the error "Installer hash does not match."

```bash
c:> winget install --accept-source-agreements --id IDHERE
```

Where can I update the hash? My package works OK when installed from Microsoft Store, from where does winget find the url it uses?

It seems other apps have this issue, too

https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/714

Answer (score 5):

There are various forms of this issue, but most likely it is due to a corporate security group policy setting.

Here's how it would look, if you had a *Group Policy* blocking Microsoft store and Discord website URL's, and trying to install using and Admin powershell.

[image]

If the Group Policy is not the culprit, then you can enable `InstallerHashOverride` with (Admin), like this:

```bash
winget settings --enable InstallerHashOverride
# Enabled admin setting 'InstallerHashOverride'.
```

Then running in a normal posh, you can try with:

```bash
winget install -i -e Discord.Discord --ignore-security-hash
```

However, we might blocked again:

[image]

...and **no**, the operation was not cancelled by me!
(But by your corporate group policy.)

Checking the error with `WinErr`, we see that the error code is a combination of:

```
8007  FRS_ERR_INSUFFICIENT_PRIV
04c7  ERROR_CANCELLED
```

Comment: it works. thank you

Comment: Is WinErr a program?  

Is it https://github.com/riyazwalikar/winerr?

This mentions support up to windows 10, not sure if you're calling a windows "WinErr" method / function

Comment: @Jonny [This one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-code-lookup-tool)

Answer (score 1):

The package manifests are stored at [winget-pkgs](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-pkgs) under the manifests folder. To update the hash you can use a tool like [winget-create](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-create) or [YamlCreate](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-pkgs/blob/master/doc/tools/YamlCreate.md). Each version of a package has its own manifest inside the proper folder constructed from the package identifier, so the hash can also be updated manually by editing the manifest directly

Answer (score 0):

it's not solvable. i tried cmd => winget install anydesk and it says "Installer hash does not match". installed it from the website.